# Performing Action inside the Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-fragments

I have MainActivity that call Fragment, the fragment call class is:

```
public class Main extends Fragment{

    //public Main(){}
    Button btn;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        try{
            btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TextView tx = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
                    tx.setText("hello World");
                }

            });
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
      // View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
       return rootView;
   }    

}
```

my problem is, i'm not able to do some activity inside this fragment.
just to find out how can i perform some activity inside this fragment i add a TextView and a Button that will change the text of TextView to "Hello World" when the button is clicked. now i try to run the application, every things fine but after clicking the button i'm getting error: "Unfprtunately the application has stopped.", i don't know why im getting error like this, i am new in android developing so please help and kindly please explain everything you add.

```
Here is the Log Cat Error:

02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:29)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
02-09 20:33:30.765: E/AndroidRuntime(13596):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post the complete error stack trace to get better help

Comment: Could you put the error trace you got in the logcat please ? Could you also post the R.layout.main xml file content it might help

Comment: Put your XML file code here as well.

Comment: Main.java:29 what line does it refer to ? Could you post the xml file as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Nothings wrong in your code, what ever you know by your code is correct, you just forget a little. base on the log-cat error, there is something's wrong with your textView id, so change your id into a different id from your main.xml and then write it into your code then try to run it. and one thing, try to remove your try catch exception, it is useless. here is the conclusion for your code.

```
public class Main extends Fragment{
    Button btn;
    TextView tx;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);
        btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tx = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.newID); //Change your textView ID into different ID
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tx.setText("hello World");
            }
        });
       return rootView;
      }

    }
```